# Counting trees with bounded degree

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, trees

I need to calculate the number of unlabelled trees with bounded maximal out-degree. I interested in both exact solution and asymptotic estimate. Can you suggest some papers about this topic or any other related materials?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest  to compute some of  these numbers and consult  the OEIS for
more  information.  (See  below  for links  containing a  considerable
number of references.)  Since the bound is on outdegree,  call it $k$,
these unlabeled trees are rooted.   We thus have from first principles
and using the Polya Enumeration Theorem the species equation

$$\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} + \mathcal{Z}
\sum_{q=1}^k \mathfrak{M}_{=q}(\mathcal{T})
= \mathcal{Z} + \mathcal{Z}
\mathfrak{M}_{\le k}(\mathcal{T}).$$

We thus obtain the functional equation

$$T(z) = z + z \sum_{q=1}^k Z(S_q)(T(z))$$

where $Z(S_q)$ is the cycle index  of the symmetric group which may be
computed from the recurrence

$$Z(S_q) = \frac{1}{q} \sum_{l=1}^q a_l Z(S_{q-l})
\quad\text{where}\quad
Z(S_0) = 1.$$

The cycle  indices are  evaluated with the  usual substitution  $a_l =
T(z^l).$ Extracting coefficients then yields

$$T_n = [[n=1]] +
[z^{n-1}] \sum_{q=1}^k Z(S_q)(T(z)).$$

This is sufficient to compute these. We present a Maple program (which
the reader is free to optimize) that gave the following results.

- $k=1$, paths (sanity check for boundary values):
  $$1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,\ldots$$

$k=2$ [OEIS A001190](https://oeis.org/A001190),
$$1, 1, 2, 3, 6, 11, 23, 46, 98, 207, 451, 983, 2179,
\\ 4850, 10905, 24631,\ldots$$

$k=3$ [OEIS A000598](https://oeis.org/A000598),
$$1, 1, 2, 4, 8, 17, 39, 89, 211, 507, 1238, 3057, 7639, 
\\ 19241, 48865, 124906,\ldots$$

$k=4$ [OEIS A036718](https://oeis.org/A036718),
$$1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 19, 45, 106, 260, 643, 1624, 4138, 10683, 
\\ 27790, 72917, 192548,\ldots$$

$k=5$ [OEIS A036721](https://oeis.org/A036721),
$$1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 20, 47, 112, 277, 693, 1766, 4547, 11852, 
\\ 31146, 82534, 220149,\ldots$$

$k=6$ [OEIS A036722](https://oeis.org/A036722),
$$1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 20, 48, 114, 283, 710, 1816, 4690, 12267, 
\\ 32338, 85978, 230080,\ldots$$

$k=7$ [OEIS A182378](https://oeis.org/A182378),
$$1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 20, 48, 115, 285, 716, 1833, 4740, 12410, 
\\ 32754, 87176, 233547,\ldots$$

$k=8$ (OEIS ends here).
$$1, 1, 2, 4, 9, 20, 48, 115, 286, 718, 1839, 4757, 12460, 
\\ 32897, 87592, 234746,\ldots$$

The  Maple code  was as  follows (another  version may  be implemented
which is faster at the expense of more memory).

```
pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;


pet_flatten_term :=
proc(varp)
local terml, d, cf, v;

    terml := [];

    cf := varp;
    for v in indets(varp) do
        d := degree(varp, v);
        terml := [op(terml), seq(v, k=1..d)];
        cf := cf/v^d;
    od;

    [cf, terml];
end;

T :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local q, idx, recurse, contrib, term, flat,
    res, sols, sol;

    if n = 1 then return 1 fi;

    recurse :=
    proc(l, m, sofar, pos)
    local fact, mult;
        fact := op(1, l[pos]);

        if pos = nops(l)  then
            if m mod fact = 0 then
                contrib := contrib +
                sofar * T(m/fact, k);
            fi;

            return;
        fi;

        for mult to floor(m/fact) do
            if m-mult*fact > 0 then
                recurse(l, m-mult*fact,
                        sofar * T(mult, k),
                        pos + 1);
            fi;
        od;
    end;

    res := T(n-1, k);

    for q from 2 to k do
        idx := pet_cycleind_symm(q);

        for term in idx do
            flat := pet_flatten_term(term);

            contrib := 0;
            recurse(flat[2], n-1, 1, 1);
            res := res + flat[1]*contrib;
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;
```

**Addendum.** An alternative species to use which has the feature that
it includes leaves that do not contribute to the count of nodes in the
tree is

$$\mathcal{T} = \epsilon + \mathcal{Z}
\mathfrak{M}_{= k}(\mathcal{T}).$$

and gives the functional equation

$$T(z) = 1 + z Z(S_k)(T(z)).$$

While  this  version   may  perhaps  be  considered   a  more  elegant
encapsulation of  the givens of  this problem  it must be  pointed out
that experiments indicate a poorer complexity by a considerable indeed
quite significant factor compared to  the first version.  What we gain
from  the reduction  in the  number of  recursive terms  is more  than
offset by  the contribution from  the constant in  $T(z^l)$, requiring
value zero  entries in the partitions  of the exponents (which  sum to
$n-1$ and are computed in the routine **recurse**).

The modified Maple routine goes as follows.

```
T :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;
local q, idx, recurse, contrib, term, flat,
    res, sols, sol;

    if n = 0 then return 1 fi;
    if k = 1 then return 1 fi;

    recurse :=
    proc(l, m, sofar, pos)
    local fact, mult;
        fact := op(1, l[pos]);

        if pos = nops(l)  then
            if m mod fact = 0 then
                contrib := contrib +
                sofar * T(m/fact, k);
            fi;

            return;
        fi;

        for mult from 0 to floor(m/fact) do
            recurse(l, m-mult*fact,
                    sofar * T(mult, k),
                    pos + 1);
        od;
    end;

    idx := pet_cycleind_symm(k);
    res := 0;

    for term in idx do
        flat := pet_flatten_term(term);

        contrib := 0;
        recurse(flat[2], n-1, 1, 1);
        res := res + flat[1]*contrib;
    od;

    res;
end;
```

**A remarkable  optimization.** The following simple  concept combined
with  memoization and  the  second functional  equation  makes for  an
algorithm that produces instant results  including for very large $n.$
This concept  is that we do  not compute the cycle  indices separately
but extract  the coefficients  from the  recurrence given  above.  The
Maple code here is quite straightforward and is included below.

```
recurse :=
proc(n, q, k)
option remember;
local res, l, m;

    if q = 0 then
        if n = 0 then
            return 1
        else
            return 0;
        fi;
    fi;

    if q = 1 then return T(n, k) fi;

    res := 0;

    for l to q do
        for m from 0 to floor(n/l) do
            res :=
            res +
            1/q*T(m, k)*
            recurse(n-m*l, q-l, k);
        od;
    od;

    res;
end;


T :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;

    if n <= 1 then return 1 fi;
    if k = 1 then return 1 fi;

    recurse(n-1, k, k);
end;
```

With this  code we can  answer questions like,  what is the  number of
unlabeled rooted trees with maximum outdegree $20$ on $100$ nodes? The
answer is

$$51384326061583754822835604490295332437941545.$$

Comment: Very nice presentation. (+1)